# Armadillo / Xcode: "functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded" error from nowhere

Tags: c++, xcode, armadillo

Firstly, I know there have been questions with this issue before, my situation differs.

I'm using the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) matrix library for a research project within Xcode. I'm quite far into the project and so far, I haven't had any issues. However, I recently made a series of changes, and when I tried recompiling the project, I got the following errors, despite not making any changes to the Armadillo header source files.

```
In file included from /Users/willandrew/Work/1-4th-Year/1Project/code/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/main.cpp:16:
In file included from /Users/willandrew/Work/1-4th-Year/1Project/code/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/TPS_RPM.h:19:
In file included from /Users/willandrew/Work/1-4th-Year/1Project/code/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/T_Params.h:14:
In file included from /usr/include/armadillo:121:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_bones.hpp:239:8: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
  void arma_fortran(arma_sgetrf)(blas_int* m, blas_int* n,  float* a, blas_int* lda, blas_int* ipiv, blas_int* info);
       ^
In file included from /Users/willandrew/Work/1-4th-Year/1Project/code/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/main.cpp:16:
In file included from /Users/willandrew/Work/1-4th-Year/1Project/code/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/TPS_RPM.h:19:
In file included from /Users/willandrew/Work/1-4th-Year/1Project/code/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/TPS-RPM(LAPACK)/T_Params.h:14:
In file included from /usr/include/armadillo:42:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:36:34: note: expanded from macro 'arma_fortran'
  #define arma_fortran(function) arma_fortran2_noprefix(function)
                                 ^
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:25:44: note: expanded from macro 'arma_fortran2_noprefix'
  #define arma_fortran2_noprefix(function) function##_
                                           ^
<scratch space>:203:1: note: expanded from here
sgetrf_
^
```

The list of errors (which are all similar) continues until Xcode halts compilation because there are too many errors. The changes I made before recompiling consisted of adding a new class and modifying some function definitions. Unfortunately however, I can't undo the changes made on each file to find the error because I had to restart my computer. I've investigated the error and I'm certain I haven't defined other methods with the same name and different return type.

This question is a bit of a longshot... but does anyone have a slight indication as to what the error means and/or what I could try doing? Let me know if you want me to add any of the source code/additional errors and thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this is your cue to enable version control in XCode.

Comment: I since have enabled VC...

Comment: You may have an errant #define somewhere, or you're making a new function named `arma_sgetrf` or `arma_sgetrf_` or `sgetrf` or `sgetrf_`, which clashes with an existing function. I strongly recommend using a version control system such as svn or git, so you can undo changes like that in the future. Alternatively, before you make large changes to your code, backup the folder with your source code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now regularly pushing to github repository. Managed to fix the issue by downgrading to Xcode 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. It was resolved when I put "armadillo" header include on top of all other includes/imports in my *.mm, *.h, *.cpp, *.hpp files.

```
#include "armadillo"
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix the issue, although I have no idea what the problem was.

During the big changes I made to the project, I upgraded to the latest Xcode. Downgrading back to 5.0.2 seems to have fixed the problems above. Be wary of the Xcode 5.1